# Can't fire event Key_Down c#

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I using form event Form1_KeyDown to move panelcontrol4

```
Private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
     {
        panelControl4.Location = new Point(panelControl4.Location.X-1,panelControl4.Location.Y);
     }
}
```

If Form1 have 1 control panelcontrol4 event worked but i add 1 control eg : simplebutton1 ... then can't fire Form1_KeyDown . Then i must enable = false simplebutton1 , then  Form1_KeyDown work

Thanks you for help

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to set [`Form.KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) to true, or if that doesn't work, use [`Control.PreviewKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks you for reply ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls on your form might automatically handle the keydown event and your code won't get called. See [Control.KeyDown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In General The [`_KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) will Occurs when a key is pressed while the control has **focus**. In your case the `Form1` doesn't have Focus at the Time of key press occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem , i must overide event **KeyDown** and **PreviewKeyDown**
@Matthew Watson